# How to do sentiment analysis in R of multiple annual reports which is in pdf format? Please provide the code as I am a beginner

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am not able to do sentiment analysis and have been facing problem most of the codes generated by AIs dont work or is always showing error.

I tried to to do the sentiment analysis of reports which are in pdf format. and i failed.

Comment: What code have you tried? What errors did you get? How are you extracting data from PDFs? Your question is likely to be closed if it doesn't meet [StackOverflow standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, we cannot write the code for you from scratch--there has to be an attempt first (with code posted), and we can go from there. If you are just looking to get started with sentiment analysis in R, this [tutorial](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment) may be useful